# Why is the sizeof a class with no non-static members always 1?

Tags: c++, class, static, sizeof

Normally, if a class has other non-static members, the size of static variables do not count towards the size of the class (or struct). For example,

```
struct A
{
   float f1;
   float f2;
   double d1;
};
```

This struct would be 4 + 4 + 8 = 16 bytes (on an x86 PC).

```
struct A
{
   float f1;
   float f2;
   static double d1;
};
```

Making the double d1 static would reduce it to 8 bytes.

However if I make *all* three members static, the size comes out to be 1. **Why is that?** In fact, removing all the variables has the same effect.

Someone told me it was because the object needs to keep track of its address, but an address is 4 bytes long isn't it? What's more, why isn't this 1 byte added to the size when I have non-static member variables? What is the purpose of this one byte if there are no non-static member variables or virtual functions?

Comment: _'the size comes out to be 1'_ Did you expect `0`?

Comment: It must have an address, so it must use at least some memory, and one byte is the smallest allocatable

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I wasn't expecting 0, but 4.